# Multiple LineDataset Animation MPChart Android

Tags: android, charts, android-animation, mpandroidchart, linechart

I am using MPChart Library. I have multiple linedatasets in my line chart. I want to animate them in linear order. Right now the animation starts simultaneously on all datasets in line chart. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
chart.setData(lineData1);
chart.invalidate(); // refresh
```

refresh your data with some delay using Handler like

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   chart.setData(lineData2);
                   chart.invalidate(); // refresh

                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                               @Override
                               public void run() {
                                chart.setData(lineData3);
                                chart.invalidate(); // refresh
                            }
                       }, 1500);
                     }
            }, 1500);
```

Comment: I have multiple linedatasets not just two. So this solution does not work for me

Comment: so you can use timer for that to do this work for updating data in LineCharts.